# Quantity Custom Fields As A part of a Title in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-fields

Im trying to add a custom field data into a Title of a post. I have quantity as a custom field and want to show it in the title of every post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Let us know exactly what you have already tried, and include a clear outline of your specific issue with the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help you resolve the problem you are having.